# Querying elasticsearch returns all documents

Tags: elasticsearch, analyzer

i wonder why a search for a specific term returns all documents of an index and not the documents containing the requested term.

Here's the index and how i set it up:
(using the elasticsearch head-plugin browser-interface)

```
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_replicas": 1,
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "dutch_stemmer": {
          "type": "dictionary_decompounder",
          "word_list": [
            "koud",
            "plaat",
            "staal",
            "fabriek"
          ]
        },
        "snowball_nl": {
          "type": "snowball",
          "language": "dutch"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "dutch": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "length",
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding",
            "dutch_stemmer",
            "snowball_nl"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

{
  "properties": {
    "test": {
      "type": "string",
      "fields": {
        "dutch": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "dutch"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then i added some docs:

```
{"test": "ijskoud"}
{"test": "plaatstaal"}
{"test": "kristalfabriek"}
```

So now when firing a search for "plaat" somehow one would expect the search would come back with the document containing "plaatstaal".

```
{
  "match": {
    "test": "plaat"
  }
}
```

However saving me further searches elasticsearch retuns all documents regardless of its text content.
Is there anything I am missing here?
Funny enough: there is a difference when using GET or POST. While using the latter brings back no hits, GET returns all documents.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure your index to use your custom analyzer:

```
PUT /some_index
{
  "settings": {
     ...
  },
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "test": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "dutch"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you have more fields that use this analyzer and don't want to specify for each the analyzer, you can do it like this for a specific type in that index:

```
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "analyzer": "dutch"
    }
  }
```

If you want ALL your types in that index to use your custom analyzer:

```
  "mappings": {
    "_default_": {
      "analyzer": "dutch"
    }
  }
```

To test your analyzer in a simple way:

```
GET /some_index/_analyze?text=plaatstaal&analyzer=dutch
```

This would be the full list of steps to perform:

```
DELETE /some_index

PUT /some_index
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_replicas": 1,
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "dutch_stemmer": {
          "type": "dictionary_decompounder",
          "word_list": [
            "koud",
            "plaat",
            "staal",
            "fabriek"
          ]
        },
        "snowball_nl": {
          "type": "snowball",
          "language": "dutch"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "dutch": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "length",
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding",
            "dutch_stemmer",
            "snowball_nl"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "test": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "dutch"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST /some_index/doc/_bulk
{"index":{}}
{"test": "ijskoud"}
{"index":{}}
{"test": "plaatstaal"}
{"index":{}}
{"test": "kristalfabriek"}

GET /some_index/doc/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "test": "plaat"
    }
  }
}
```

And the result of the search:

```
{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1.987628,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "some_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "jlGkoJWoQfiVGiuT_TUCpg",
            "_score": 1.987628,
            "_source": {
               "test": "plaatstaal"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: thank you! now the mapping is in place, do you have any idea why a search for "plaat" does not return the document containing "plaatstaal". Do i have to declare the analyzer within the request body?

Comment: `curl -XGET localhost:9200/foo/_search -d '{ "query":{ "match": {"test": "plaat" }}} '
`

Comment: After changing the mapping of the index, you need to re-index the documents. Did you do that?

Comment: yes i did - in fact i deleted the index, then recreated it with the same settings and mapping. As the last step i added the documents. As you can see the mapping / analyzer is configured properly
`{
    tokens: [
    {
        token: plaatstal
        start_offset: 0
        end_offset: 10
        type: <ALPHANUM>
        position: 1
    },
    {
        token: plat
        start_offset: 0
        end_offset: 10
        type: <ALPHANUM>
        position: 1
    }
    {
        token: stal
        start_offset: 0
        end_offset: 10
        type: <ALPHANUM>
        position: 1
    }
]
}`

Comment: I have updated my answer with a full list of commands, just like I tested in my test environment.

Comment: that's what i get doing the same: `{"took":0,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":1,"successful":1,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":0,"max_score":null,"hits":[]}}`

Comment: If you do this `GET /some_index/doc/_search` do you get back your three documents correctly?

Comment: yes, all three documents `curl -XGET localhost:9200/foo/_search
{"took":1,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":1,"successful":1,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":3,"max_score":1.0,"hits":[{"_index":"foo","_type":"bar","_id":"Avv1cfOESfeWPEhGgX5jEA","_score":1.0,"_source":{"test": "ijskoud"}},{"_index":"foo","_type":"bar","_id":"COKA1MRCQHyJvyxe2cFJjw","_score":1.0,"_source":{"test": "plaatstaal"}},{"_index":"foo","_type":"bar","_id":"T-2JEPP5SJiXrrSU6x68kg","_score":1.0,"_source":{"test": "kristalfabriek"}}]}}`

Comment: elasticsearch 1.3.1, running on ubuntu 14.04lts

Comment: You must be doing something wrong (not following the commands accordingly, mistyping something, maybe connecting to a different ES instance etc) because I tested your exact environment and exact data and commands and everything works as expected.

Comment: Can you execute this command and post what you get back? `GET /foo/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "fielddata_fields": ["test"]
}`

Comment: got it! i was wrong using the _mapping handler to separately add the mapping to the "test" field. Now it works with the following:
`curl -XPOST localhost:9200/foo/bar/_mapping -d '{
"properties": {
    "test": {
        "type": "string",
        "analyzer": "dutch"
    }
}
}'`
Somehow when using your instructions where the mapping is part of the index creation - that did not work for me in the first place. Now it does. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

When you are using GET you do not pass the request body, so search is performed without any filter and all documents are returned.

When you are using POST your search query does get passed on. It doesn't return anything probably because your document is not getting analyzed as you intended it to.

Comment: but when executing a search in a shell using curl there's no difference between GET / POST right?
`curl -XGET localhost:9200/foo/_search -d '{
"query":{ "match": {"test": "plaatstaal" }}}
'
`